# How to set text on md-Switch?

Tags: css, angularjs, material-design, angular-ui, angular-material

I am trying to set informational text on md-switch that comes under material angular design so that user can know what is the current state of a field value. Pictorial representation of what I want can be[image: Text on md-switch]

How is this done folks? I am new to material design.

Comment: https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdSwitch

Comment: couldn't find anything in the documentation of mdSwitch directive to achieve this. Can you give me a straight pointer please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this to add a label to `md-bar` using CSS:

```
md-switch.inline-label .md-bar::before {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 9px;
  line-height: 13px;

  content: "off";
  right: 0;
  padding-right: 3px;      
}

md-switch.inline-label.md-checked .md-bar::before {
  content: "on";
  left: 0;
  padding-left: 3px;
}
```

Apply the class `inline-label` to your `md-switch`:

```
<md-switch class="inline-label" ng-model="data.cb1" aria-label="Switch 1">
  Switch 1: {{ data.cb1 }}
</md-switch>
```

```js
angular.module('MyApp', ['ngMaterial'])
  .controller('SwitchDemoCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.data = {
      cb1: true,
      cb4: true,
      cb5: false
    };

    $scope.message = 'false';

    $scope.onChange = function(cbState) {
      $scope.message = cbState;
    };
  });
```

```css
.switchdemoBasicUsage .inset {
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-top: 25px;
}
md-switch.wlabel .md-bar::before {
  content: "off";
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  font-size: 9px;
  line-height: 13px;
  padding-right: 3px;
}
md-switch.wlabel.md-checked .md-bar::before {
  content: "on";
  left: 0;
  padding-left: 3px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-aria.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.3/angular-material.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.3/angular-material.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="inset switchdemoBasicUsage" ng-controller="SwitchDemoCtrl" ng-cloak="" ng-app="MyApp">
  <md-switch class="wlabel" ng-model="data.cb1" aria-label="Switch 1">
    Switch 1: {{ data.cb1 }}
  </md-switch>

  <md-switch ng-model="data.cb2" aria-label="Switch 2" ng-true-value="'yup'" ng-false-value="'nope'" class="md-warn">
    Switch 2 (md-warn): {{ data.cb2 }}
  </md-switch>

  <md-switch ng-disabled="true" aria-label="Disabled switch" ng-model="disabledModel">
    Switch (Disabled)
  </md-switch>

  <md-switch ng-disabled="true" aria-label="Disabled active switch" ng-model="data.cb4">
    Switch (Disabled, Active)
  </md-switch>

  <md-switch class="md-primary" md-no-ink="" aria-label="Switch No Ink" ng-model="data.cb5">
    Switch (md-primary): No Ink
  </md-switch>

  <md-switch ng-model="data.cb6" aria-label="Switch 6" ng-change="onChange(data.cb6)">
    Switch 6 message: {{ message }}
  </md-switch>
</div>
```

Comment: Does the job for now, hence accepting as answer. But we still should have more robust way to handle this instead of just css property as we won't probably be able to handle language localization in css property dynamically.

Comment: The codepen appears to be broken. If you're willing to fix it (And better yet, make it into a snippet on stackoverflow), I'll toss you an upvote.

Comment: @FrankerZ here you go

Comment: Thank you for the addition =)